# Behavior of a non-linear differential equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Let us consider the following differential equation
$$
\dot{x}(t)=a - b\sin(x(t)), \quad a,b\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

> **My question.** Suppose $a>|b|$ and $x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. Can the solution to the above equation be written in the form
>   $$
> x(t) = at + r(a,t),
> $$
>   where the term $r(a,t)$ is such that $r(a,t)\to 0$ for $a\to \infty$?

**PS:** Of course, the explicit solution can be computed via symbolic software tools, such as Wolfram Alpha. However, the symbolic expression (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dx(t)%2Fdt%20%3D%20a%20-%20b*sin(x))) looks quite messy and does not give much information on the behavior of the solution for $a\to\infty$...

Comment: I believe that my question is a research-level one, so I don’t understand why it received a downvote. Anyway, if the MO community think this is not actually the case, could someone please migrate it to MSE in order to avoid cross-postings? Thanks!

Comment: The questions does not seem obvious to me. Unless you know it is a standard result in ODE's don't vote it down.

Comment: "The" solution?  There are infinitely many, unless you set an initial condition.  Do you mean "some solution", or "every solution" instead of "the solution"?  Also, if $|a| \le |b|$ all solutions are bounded.  Do you mean to restrict to the case $a > |b|$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: You are right, thanks! I've just edited my question according to your comments.

Comment: Did you try writing x in the desired form and plugging it into the equation?  I don't see how you could then reach your conclusion of r going to zero.  Gerhard "The Derivative Changes Too Much" Paseman, 2018.04.03.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: I do not know what the "exact" form of the term $r(a,t)$ is. I guessed its limiting behavior for $a\to \infty$ on the basis of some numerical evidences. (And, of course, my guess could be wrong)

Comment: I normally don't challenge a post of Robert Israel, because he does quality work. I suspect his O terms in this case and think a different conclusion should be reached. When I derive an equation for r from your problem, I find r has a derivative that is near -b sin(at), and thus r oscillates without substantial decay, even as a grows large.  Gerhard "I'm Seeing More Of Nonzero" Paseman, 2018.04.03.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Robert Israel's answer looks correct to me. So could you please elaborate your thoughts?

Comment: He presents the error as 1/a*a times something. Since b could be as big as a (we don't know if it is being held constant ) I see it as 1/a times x times some  geometric series like thing varying with x. So I do not see it as (hold b and hold x, and let a get big).  That plus the oscillation of r  is how I see it. Gerhard "It's A Matter Of Perspective" Paseman, 2018.04.03.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case $a > |b|$, so the solutions are unbounded.  The equation is separable, and we get implicit solutions of the form

$$ t = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{ds}{a - b \sin(s)}  $$

which we can expand in a series in $1/a$ (uniformly convergent in $s$).  Absolute convergence justifies interchanging sum and integral, so (for fixed $x$ and $b$)

$$\eqalign{ t &= \int_{x_0}^x ds\; \sum_{k=0}^\infty (b \sin(s))^k a^{-1-k}\cr
&= \frac{x-x_0}{a} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty a^{-1-k}b^k \int_{x_0}^x \sin^k(s)\; ds\cr &= \frac{x-x_0}{a} + O(a^{-2})}$$

Thus $x - x_0 = a t + O(a^{-1})$, which I believe is what you meant.

Comment: Perhaps, shouldn’t be $b^k$ instead of $(-b)^k$?

Comment: Oops, yes.  Editing

Answer (score 2):

Take the ODE
$$
\tag{$*$}
\dot{x}(t) = a - b \sin(x(t))
$$
on the one-dimensional torus $\mathbb{R}/2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$.  The vector field has no zeros, so there is a unique periodic orbit, with period
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{d\xi}{a - b \sin(\xi)} =
\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}.
$$
Return now to $(*)$ on the real line $\mathbb{R}$.  We have
$$
x\!\left(t + \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}\right) = x(t) + 2 \pi \quad \text{for all }t \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Put
$$
h(t) := x(t) - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} t.
$$
$h$ is easily seen to be periodic, with period $2\pi/\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$.  Consequently, we have, for any solution $x(\cdot)$ to $(*)$,
$$
x(t) = \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} t + h(t).
$$
So,
$$
r(a, t) = (\sqrt{a^2 - b^2} - a)t + h(t),
$$
which, for a fixed $t$, converges to $h(t)$ as $a \to \infty$.